24.04 Desktop RDP password unstable
Just installed 24.04, and can't get a usable RDP connection from Windows.
When 24.04's setup will work for me, I change the password to the memorable one I use on my private LAN.
Reboot Ubuntu, and it's done me the (unforgivable) service of changing the password to something random, unmemorable, and unwieldy. Combined with Windows 11 Home editions refusal to remember any RDP password for a remote machine, and I'm ready to scream.
T.

Blank screen, doesn't work with any setting, with Remote Desktop on or off. No SSH, either!

Okay, now I get a login screen. I login, then screen goes blank. Still no SSH. Turn it on, it turns itself off. I'm logged out on the Ubuntu machine serving the RDP session.

Does this answer solve your RDP black screen problem? )Also see this answer. Ask a new question about ssh.

All sorted. Thank you user68186.

It appears that trying to use Ubuntu's Remote Desktop server, when I should be using 24.04's new Remote Login feature, was the cause for the ever changing login password. Unfortunately, the new Remote Login server didn't work for me (blank screen after login). The solution was to turn off Ubuntu's Remote Desktop and Remote Login, and install xrdp. I tried that and got a very odd looking desktop, so removed that installation and went with the amazing xrdp installation script available from the link below:
"We are still maintaining the xrdp-installer script even if Gnome Remote login feature is available and provide basic RDP support."
https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19814
Even redirected sound works!
